# Removing Linux Partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning

Hello all Had a complete disaster trying to install Linux Mint which caused a corruption in my start boot and sent my windows startup into a loop. I did a start menu fix from recovery and managed to recover my windows boot but the Linux boot screen disappeared. Imagining the PC was dead I am now back in a position where windows works but I cant see or get to Linux. At this time I have decided to remove all partitions created by Linux to be looked at a later date.
Currently this is my partition layout

[image: image description here]

Can you please confirm which partitions need to go

Many thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say that the Linux partition is
Disk 0 partition 6.

This is based on these facts :

- It's large
- It's not NTFS
- It doesn't have a drive-letter.

I would suggest to use Device Manager to assign it a drive-letter and see
if Explorer can do anything with it. If it can't, then this is most
likely the Linux partition (remove the drive-letter).

Note that for dual-boot you need to disable Fast Startup in Windows,
or your boot could have problems.